# Salesforce Experience Cloud Custom Theme Layout show Logo

Tags: experience-cloud

I've installed Vertical Menu Navigation for Experience Cloud
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000GuMdYUAV&tab=d

I'm struggled withe the following:
In the custom theme layout how can i add the logo to the header?
Can i make the menu always expanded rather than collapsible?

Comment: You will have to check with the vendor.